# Defintion of convergence of sequcences

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I am new and taking a analysis course and asking a stupid question.

Some places they write that the convergence of sequences is given by
$\forall{\epsilon}\geq{0}$ $\exists{N\in{N}}$ s.t $||x_n-x||<\epsilon, n\geq{N}$.

and other places
$\forall{\epsilon}\geq{0}$ $\exists{N\in{N}}$ s.t $||x_n-x||\leq\epsilon, n\geq{N}$

What is difference between $||x_n-x||\leq\epsilon$ and $||x_n-x||<\epsilon$

as they booth depends on $N$ and $n$?

Comment: In fact, both definitions are equivalent, and it could be a very good exercise to prove it !

Comment: Thank you for incredible fast answer. How will the proof start?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are equivalent:

- If there is a $N\in\Bbb N$ such that $n\geqslant N\implies \|x-x_n\|<\varepsilon$, then $n\geqslant N\implies \|x-x_n\|\leqslant\varepsilon$.
- If there is a $N\in\Bbb N$ such that $n\geqslant N\implies \|x-x_n\|\leqslant\frac\varepsilon2$, then $n\geqslant N\implies \|x-x_n\|<\varepsilon$.

Comment: Can it also be shown by least upper bound property

Comment: @TorErikHaavik The argument does not need anything as strong as the least upper bound property. It will work just as it is for the rational numbers, where the least upper bound property fails.

Comment: how can it be that $||x_n-x||<\epsilon$ then $||x_n-x||\leq{\epsilon}$ for the same $n$ or is it sufficiently large $n$ that satisfies booth

Comment: If a number $a$ is smaller than a number $b$, then, in particular, it is smaller than or equal to $b$.

Comment: sorry if I am really stupid but is this correct thinking so since $a<b$ then $a\leq{b}$ , that is $a<b$ or $a=b$ but we know equality can never happen since it is assumed $a<b$?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.